# VerifyError When Running jUnit Test on Android 1.6

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-sdk-1.6, verifyerror

Here's what I'm trying to run on Android 1.6:

```
package com.healthlogger.test;

public class AllTests extends TestSuite
{
    public static Test suite()
    {
        return new TestSuiteBuilder(AllTests.class).includeAllPackagesUnderHere().build();
    }
}
```

and:

```
package com.healthlogger.test;

public class RecordTest extends AndroidTestCase
{

    /**
     * Ensures that the constructor will not take a null data tag.
     */
    @Test(expected=AssertionFailedError.class)
    public void testNullDataTagInConstructor()
    {
        Record r = new Record(null, Calendar.getInstance(), "Data");
        fail("Failed to catch null data tag.");
    }
}
```

The main project is HealthLogger. These are run from a separate test project (HealthLoggerTest).  HealthLogger and jUnit4 are in HealthLoggerTest's build path. jUnit4 is also in HealthLogger's build path. The class "Record" is located in com.healthlogger.

Commenting out the "@Test..." and "Record r..." lines allows this test to run. When they are uncommented, I get a VerifyError exception. I am severely blocked by this; why is it happening?

---

EDIT: some info from logcat after the crash:

```
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): Uncaught handler: thread main exiting due to uncaught exception                     
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): java.lang.VerifyError: com.healthlogger.test.RecordTest       E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors(Native Method)
    E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at java.lang.Class.getConstructors(Class.java:507) E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at  android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping$TestCasePredicate.hasValidConstructor(TestGrouping.java:226) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping$TestCasePredicate.apply(TestGrouping.java:215)  

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):    at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping$TestCasePredicate.apply(TestGrouping.java:211) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.select(TestGrouping.java:170) E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.selectTestClasses(TestGrouping.java:160) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.testCaseClassesInPackage(TestGrouping.java:154) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestGrouping.addPackagesRecursive(TestGrouping.java:115) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.test.suitebuilder.TestSuiteBuilder.includePackages(TestSuiteBuilder.java:103) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onCreate(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:321) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:3848) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2800(ActivityThread.java:116) E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123) E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4203) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723): at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:791) 

E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:549) E/AndroidRuntime( 3723):        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android JUnit Tests failing with java.lang.VerifyError](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5437595/android-junit-tests-failing-with-java-lang-verifyerror)

Comment: You might be correct. Unfortunately, I can no longer try to verify a solution to this problem - I am without a 1.6 device. If you feel that the two are similar enough please feel free to delete / close this question.

Comment: Does it occur in the emulator? If so, you can try it on the 1.6 emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can occur when you forget to export all dependencies for a test project.

In Eclipse, go to the Java Build Path properties for your projects (both the main project and the test project).  Go to the Organize/Export tab and make sure you check all dependencies (select all, except for any JRE or Classpath Container that might be listed).